# My Python Wumpus game not ending

Tags: python

I'm doing the Wumpus game from Hello Python.

Unfortunately whether the player wastes his only arrow or the Wumpus eats him the game does not end.

I've tried fiddling with the code but to be honest I'm just a beginner and still learning.

Here is the code

```
    from random import choice

import random

cave_numbers = range(0, 20)
caves =[]

for i in cave_numbers:
    caves.append([])

unvisited_caves = range(0,20)
visited_caves = [0]
#unvisited caves == []
unvisited_caves.remove(0)

while unvisited_caves != []:
    i = choice(visited_caves)
    if len(caves[i]) >= 3:
        break

    next_cave = choice(unvisited_caves)
    caves[i].append(next_cave)
    caves[next_cave].append(i)

    visited_caves.append(next_cave)
    unvisited_caves.remove(next_cave)

    for number in cave_numbers:
        print number, ":", caves[number]
    print '----------'

    for i in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[i]) < 3:
            passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
            caves[i].append(passage_to)

        for i in cave_numbers:
            while len(caves[i]) < 3:
                passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
                caves[i].append(passage_to)

            for number in cave_numbers:
                print number, ":", caves[number]
            print '----------'

for i in cave_numbers:
    for j in range(3):
        passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
        caves[i].append(passage_to)
print caves
wumpus_location = choice(cave_numbers)
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)
#while player_location == wumpus_location
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)

print "Welcome to Hunt the Wumpus!"
print "You can see", len(cave_numbers), "caves"
print "To play, just type the number"
print "of the cave you wish to enter next"

while True:

    def print_location(player_location):
        """ Tell the player where they are """
        print "You are in cave ", player_location
        print "From here you can see caves:"
        print caves[player_location]
        if wumpus_location in caves[player_location]:
            print "I smell and horrible wumpus!"

    def setup_caves(cave_numbers):
        """ Create the starting list of caves """
        caves = []
        for cave in cave_numbers:
            caves.append([])
        return caves

    def link_caves():
        """ Make sure all of the caves are conneceted with two-way tunnels """
        while unvisited_caves != []:
            this_cave = choose_cave(visited_caves)
            next_cave = choose_cave(unvisited_caves)
            create_tunnel(this_cave, next_cave)
            visit_cave(next_cave)

    def finish_caves():
        """ Link the rest of the caves with one-way tunnels """
        for cave in cave_numbers:
            while len(caves[cave]) < 3:
                passage_to = choose_cave(cave_numbers)
                caves[cave].append(passage_to)

    def ask_for_cave():
        """Ask the player to choose a cave from their current_location."""
        player_input = raw_input("Which cave?")
        if (not player_input.isdigit() or 
            int(player_input) not in caves[player_location]):
            print player_input + "?"
            print "That's not a direction that I can see!"
        else:
            return  int(player_input)

    def get_action():
        """ Find out what the player wants to do next. """
        print "What do you do next?"
        print "     m) move"
        print "     a) fire an arrow"
        action = raw_input(">")
        if action == "m" or action == "a":
            return action
        else:
            print action + "?"
            print "That's not an action that I know about"
            return None

    def do_movement():
        print "Moving...."
        new_location = ask_for_cave()
        if new_location is None:
            return player_location
        else:
            return new_location

    def do_shooting():
        print "Firing..."
        shoot_at = ask_for_cave()
        if shoot_at is None:
            return False

        if shoot_at == wumpus_location:
            print "Kapow!  Well done buddy, you shot the mighty wumpus!"
            print "You are the mighty wumpus hunter."
        else:
            print "Twang... clatter, clatter!"
            print "You wasted your ONLY arrow!"
            print "Empty handed, you begin the "
            print "long trek back to your village.  A failure."
            return True



    #...

    while 1:
        print_location(player_location)

        action = get_action()
        if action is None:
            continue

        if action == "m":
            player_location = do_movement()
            if player_location == wumpus_location:
                print "Argh, the wumpus ATE you!"
                print "Game over bro, game over!"
                break

        if action == "a":
            game_over = do_shooting()
            if game_over:
                break
```

Comment: What should happen? 1. You are not tracking howmany arrows the player has, 2. You have only a `break` command where you want the game to end (I think), 3. You use a `while True` syntax where you probably should do a `while condition == some_state` check, etc.

Comment: The player has one chance to fire. If he misses game over. If he gets eaten game over.

Answer (score 1):

Your program never stops because you are using `while True:`, additionally you had a `while 1:` inside the other while loop (which must have been a mistake). You can fix this by using a single conditional check as shown below:

```
# You had "while True:" here directly followed by a "while 1:",
# meaning that no matter what happened (short of a sys.exit()) 
# these loops would not stop.
game_over = False
while game_over == False: 

    print_location(player_location)

    action = get_action()
    if action is None:
        continue

    if action == "m":
        player_location = do_movement()
        if player_location == wumpus_location:
            print "Argh, the wumpus ATE you!"
            print "Game over bro, game over!"
            break

    if action == "a":
        # Because the while loop is now connected to game_over,
        # we can skip the if statement that you had.
        game_over = do_shooting()
```

I have taken the liberty to take all your functions outside of the `while` loop as they are just making it harder to read. I will also suggest you to try to learn how to use `main()` instead of this linear format of programming, it will help you out in the long run ;)

The full code that I used to run it is below, I have only added it because based on the comments your program still doesn't end.

```
from random import choice

import random

cave_numbers = range(0, 20)
caves =[]

for i in cave_numbers:
    caves.append([])

unvisited_caves = range(0,20)
visited_caves = [0]
#unvisited caves == []
unvisited_caves.remove(0)

while unvisited_caves != []:
    i = choice(visited_caves)
    if len(caves[i]) >= 3:
        break

    next_cave = choice(unvisited_caves)
    caves[i].append(next_cave)
    caves[next_cave].append(i)

    visited_caves.append(next_cave)
    unvisited_caves.remove(next_cave)

    for number in cave_numbers:
        print number, ":", caves[number]
    print '----------'

    for i in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[i]) < 3:
            passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
            caves[i].append(passage_to)

        for i in cave_numbers:
            while len(caves[i]) < 3:
                passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
                caves[i].append(passage_to)

            for number in cave_numbers:
                print number, ":", caves[number]
            print '----------'

for i in cave_numbers:
    for j in range(3):
        passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
        caves[i].append(passage_to)
print caves
wumpus_location = choice(cave_numbers)
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)
#while player_location == wumpus_location
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)

print "Welcome to Hunt the Wumpus!"
print "You can see", len(cave_numbers), "caves"
print "To play, just type the number"
print "of the cave you wish to enter next"

def print_location(player_location):
    """ Tell the player where they are """
    print "You are in cave ", player_location
    print "From here you can see caves:"
    print caves[player_location]
    if wumpus_location in caves[player_location]:
        print "I smell and horrible wumpus!"

def setup_caves(cave_numbers):
    """ Create the starting list of caves """
    caves = []
    for cave in cave_numbers:
        caves.append([])
    return caves

def link_caves():
    """ Make sure all of the caves are conneceted with two-way tunnels """
    while unvisited_caves != []:
        this_cave = choose_cave(visited_caves)
        next_cave = choose_cave(unvisited_caves)
        create_tunnel(this_cave, next_cave)
        visit_cave(next_cave)

def finish_caves():
    """ Link the rest of the caves with one-way tunnels """
    for cave in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[cave]) < 3:
            passage_to = choose_cave(cave_numbers)
            caves[cave].append(passage_to)

def ask_for_cave():
    """Ask the player to choose a cave from their current_location."""
    player_input = raw_input("Which cave?")
    if (not player_input.isdigit() or 
        int(player_input) not in caves[player_location]):
        print player_input + "?"
        print "That's not a direction that I can see!"
    else:
        return  int(player_input)

def get_action():
    """ Find out what the player wants to do next. """
    print "What do you do next?"
    print "     m) move"
    print "     a) fire an arrow"
    action = raw_input(">")
    if action == "m" or action == "a":
        return action
    else:
        print action + "?"
        print "That's not an action that I know about"
        return None

def do_movement():
    print "Moving...."
    new_location = ask_for_cave()
    if new_location is None:
        return player_location
    else:
        return new_location

def do_shooting():
    print "Firing..."
    shoot_at = ask_for_cave()
    if shoot_at is None:
        return False

    if shoot_at == wumpus_location:
        print "Kapow!  Well done buddy, you shot the mighty wumpus!"
        print "You are the mighty wumpus hunter."
    else:
        print "Twang... clatter, clatter!"
        print "You wasted your ONLY arrow!"
        print "Empty handed, you begin the "
        print "long trek back to your village.  A failure."
        return True

game_over = False
while game_over == False:


    print_location(player_location)

    action = get_action()
    if action is None:
        continue

    if action == "m":
        player_location = do_movement()
        if player_location == wumpus_location:
            print "Argh, the wumpus ATE you!"
            print "Game over bro, game over!"
            break

    if action == "a":
        game_over = do_shooting()
```

Comment: That seems like a way better solution. To be honest I don't like this book too much. Thank you.

Comment: My game still isn't ending. :-(

Comment: @ev1lchris I have added the full section of code, although the only relevant changes are in the first section that I posted in the answer.

Comment: Are those indents after game_over == False correct?  Python is telling me there is unexpected indentation.

Comment: @ev1lchris Which indents? The above code runs fine for me if I copy/paste it (into Geany)...